# What is a lightweight script/jQuery extension that implements a draggable divider?

Tags: javascript, html

I need a JavaScript script or a jQuery plugin that lets me resize two divs accordingly by dragging a horizontal "divider" (well, it divides horizontal, but the divider line is vertical).
Better leave a picture here:

```
 _______________________
|           |           |
|           |           |
|           |           |
|       <-- | -->       |
|           |           |
|           |           |
|           |           |
|___________|___________|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [jQuery Splitter Plugin](http://methvin.com/splitter/). Works quite well.