# User-draggable sections of a webapp

Tags: user-interface, draggable, jsfiddle

I'm wondering how to replicate the functionality of the draggable column/row dividers such as found at http://jsfiddle.net/.

Is this built on top of some library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The draggable dividers in the jsfiddle site are implemented using the code in `jsfiddle.net/js/LayoutCM.js` and `jsfiddle.net/codemirror/js/codemirror.js`.

Note: The new code change in SO makes it really finiciky to directly link to the jsfiddle implementation in order to explain how they implemented something.

Other relevant StackOverflow questions include

- [Resize elements by dragging divider handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061414/resize-elements-by-dragging-divider-handler)
- [Draggable div without jquery ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569095/draggable-div-without-jquery-ui)
- [What is a lightweight script jquery extension that implements a draggable divide ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810850/what-is-a-lightweight-script-jquery-extension-that-implements-a-draggable-divide)

The is functionality is provided various projects including jquery plugins and other javascript scripts

- [jquery-divider](https://github.com/weblinc/jquery-divider)
- [jquery-splitter](http://methvin.com/splitter/)
- [splitplane](http://www.jools.net/projects/javascript/splitpanes/)
- [jqueryui Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) (used as component to implement)
- [jqueryui Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)(used as component to implement)
- [mootools splitter](http://verens.com/2007/07/25/a-few-splitter-enhancements/)
- [yui resize](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/resize/) (used as component to implement)
- [jquery split plane](https://github.com/shagstrom/split-pane)

Also see other resources including

- [An example jquery splitplane implementation](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html)
- [The example splitplane in Google's closure library](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/splitpane.html)
- [split plane control in yui example](http://skypoetsworld.blogspot.com/2007/09/splitpane-control-yui.html)

Most people seem to use an existing jquery plugin or make their own implementation using the Draggable and Resizable components, for example code see the other StackOverflow posts mentioned.